# Laravel find() query doesn't bind any data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Using laravel 4.0

This is my call to find:

```
User::find(2)->first()
```

And this is the result from `getQueryLog()`:

```
[query] => select * from `users` limit 1
[bindings] => Array
    (
    )
```

I expected that it would use a `where = ?`.

I'm almost certain this worked well until it didn't.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `User::find(2)` will return user with primary key 2. check [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent), why are you useing first()

Comment: I think `->first()` is somehow, working against you. Have you tried without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to use:

```
$user = User::find(2);
```

It will get you User with primary key `2`.

You don't need to and cannot use `find` with `first` - there's only one User with given primary key so Eloquent automatically get user and you don't need to use `first` in this case. You could use first if you would like to get user this way:

```
$user = User::where('id','2')->first();
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```
$user = User::find(2);
```

(assuming `id` is primary key)